# scrapy redirecting to 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, scrapy

newbie to scrapy here. I'm trying to scrape some basic data from a bridge website and I keep getting redirected back to localhost for some reason.

This doesn't happen for most other websites (e.g. the dmoz example in the tutorial). My hunch is that I haven't set something up to deal with the domain in question. My spider (almost exact same as the one in the tutorial, except with URLs changed):

```
import scrapy

class BboSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bbo"
    allowed_domains = ["bridgebase.com"]
    start_urls = [
            "http://www.bridgebase.com/vugraph/schedule.php"
            ]

    # rules for parsing main response
    def parse(self, response):
        filename = 'test.html' 
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

The error I'm getting is (the relevant part):

```
2016-01-23 14:21:50 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.4 started (bot: bbo)
2016-01-23 14:21:50 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-01-23 14:21:50 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'bbo.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['bbo.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'bbo'}
2016-01-23 14:21:50 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-01-23 14:21:50 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-01-23 14:21:50 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-01-23 14:21:50 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2016-01-23 14:21:50 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-01-23 14:21:50 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-01-23 14:21:50 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-01-23 14:21:54 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://127.0.0.1> from <GET http://www.bridgebase.com/vugraph/schedule.php>
2016-01-23 14:21:54 [scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://127.0.0.1> (failed 1 times): Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.
```

This is probably a super basic question, but I'm having a lot of trouble even figuring out where to start. Does anyone have any hunches with where to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide a `User-Agent` header to pretend to be a real browser.

You can do it directly in the spider by providing the `headers` dictionary while returning the `scrapy.Request` from `start_requests()`:

```
import scrapy

class BboSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "bbo"
    allowed_domains = ["bridgebase.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request("http://www.bridgebase.com/vugraph/schedule.php", headers={
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36"
        })

    # rules for parsing main response
    def parse(self, response):
        filename = 'test.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Or, you may just set the [`USER_AGENT` project setting](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent).